# Why does an insert that groups by the primary key throw a primary key constraint violation error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an insert statement that's throwing a primary key error but I don't see how I could possibly be inserting duplicate key values.

First I create a temp table with a primary key.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED //Note: I've tried committed and uncommited, neither materially affects the behavior. See screenshots below for proof.

IF (OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#P')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #P;

CREATE TABLE #P(idIsbn INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, price SMALLMONEY, priceChangedDate DATETIME);
```

Then I pull prices from the Prices table, grouping by idIsbn, which is the primary key in the temp table.

```
INSERT  INTO #P(idIsbn, price, priceChangedDate)
SELECT  idIsbn ,
        MIN(lowestPrice) ,
        MIN(priceChangedDate)
FROM Price p
WHERE p.idMarketplace = 3100
GROUP BY p.idIsbn
```

I understand that grouping by idIsbn by definition makes it unique. The idIsbn in the prices table is: `[idIsbn] [int] NOT NULL`.

But every once in a while when I run this query I get this error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#P________AED35F8119E85FC5'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.#P'. The duplicate key value is (1447858).
```

NOTE: I've got a lot of questions about timing. I will select this statement, press F5, and no error will occur. Then I'll do it again, and it will fail, then I'll run it again and again and it will succeed a couple times before it fails again. I guess what I'm saying is that I can find no pattern for when it will succeed and when it won't.

How can I be inserting duplicate rows if (A) I just created the table brand new before inserting into it and (B) I'm grouping by the column designed to be the primary key?

For now, I'm solving the problem with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`, but I'd really like to know the root cause of the problem.

Here is what I'm actually seeing in my SSMS window. There is nothing more and nothing less:

[image]

@@Version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64) 
    Apr  3 2015 14:50:02 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Execution Plan:
[image]

Here is an example of what it looks like when it runs fine. Here I'm using READ COMMITTED, but it doesn't matter b/c I get the error no matter whether I read it committed or uncommited.
[image]

Here is another example of it failing, this time w/ READ COMMITTED.

[image]

Also:

- I get the same error whether I'm populating a temp table or a
  persistent table.
- When I add `option (maxdop 1)` to the end of the insert it seems to fail every time, though I can't be exhaustively sure of that b/c I can't run it for infinity. But it seems to be the case.

Here is the definition of the price table. Table has 25M rows. 108,529 updates in the last hour.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Price](
    [idPrice] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idIsbn] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idMarketplace] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lowestPrice] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [offers] [smallint] NULL,
    [priceDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [priceChangedDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_Price] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idPrice] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uc_idIsbn_idMarketplace] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [idIsbn] ASC,
    [idMarketplace] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And the two non-clustered indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Price_idMarketplace_INC_idIsbn_lowestPrice_priceDate] ON [dbo].[Price]
(
    [idMarketplace] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [idIsbn],
    [lowestPrice],
    [priceDate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Price_idMarketplace_priceChangedDate_INC_idIsbn_lowestPrice] ON [dbo].[Price]
(
    [idMarketplace] ASC,
    [priceChangedDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [idIsbn],
    [lowestPrice]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Are you completely sure that you are inserting rows immediately after creating that temp table?

Comment: What is the datatype of `idsku’ in the source table?

Comment: Why use `group by` here? Also does `idSku` have unique index (or is it PK) in table `Prices` ?

Comment: it seems like in your table the column is `idIsbn` instead of `idSku`?

Comment: No idea then, if it was a different datatype potentially it might have been different actual values that cast to the same int. Can you post the entire script showing the create and insert?

Comment: Is it possible that there is an error creating the temporary table -- because it already exists -- and hence the inserts conflict with existing data?

Comment: are you running this query more than once from the beginning?, as in you press F5 on the same query window?

Comment: `read uncommitted`, I would imagine that causes it. ["`read uncommitted` isolation adds... Missed/duplicate rows due to allocation-ordered scans"](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level).

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tamarick_hill/archive/2013/05/06/pros-cons-of-using-read-uncommitted-and-nolock.aspx

Comment: @GSerg but if it is a stream aggregate then the values will be sorted next to each other even if the same row is read twice. And if a hash aggregate they will still get hashed into the same bucket. So how can that cause duplicates after the group by?

Comment: just to be sure, you get this error when you run that query once?, the first time?

Comment: Do you get a parallel plan? What is your `@@version`?

Comment: Just for fun, could you post the execution plan?

Comment: If I change it to "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED", it still gives me the error sometimes.

Comment: but never the first time, right?

Comment: What do you get if you just run the SELECT without the INSERT?  That should show you what you *would* insert.  Also, does the error always mention that ID (1447858) or does it change?

Comment: The id changes every time. I could just run the select, but it returns like 5 million rows, so it'd be hard to suss it out. And if I do a HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 of course it always gives me 0.

Comment: @Trevor you have not even 2008R2. And note there is SP4 for 2008. Test on a newer server.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue at all if you force a serial plan with `option (maxdop 1)` by the way?

Comment: Same situation if I append `option (maxdop 1)` to the query

Comment: Also added GO statements after creation of the temp table to see if that would do anything. Nothing.

Comment: @MartinSmith Actually, when I added `option (maxdop 1)` it seems to fail every time.

Comment: With the same key value every time?

Comment: Nope, different value every time.

Comment: Is this table encountering a heavy rate of data modifications all the time?

Comment: If you swap your `DROP TABLE #P;` for `BEGIN PRINT 'Dropping #P'; DROP TABLE #P; END;` to confirm your DROP is actually working, do you always see it happen?

Comment: @GSerg - though in this case the plan doesn't have either form of aggregate. I guess there must be a unique constraint that ensures there are no duplicates and so it gets optimised out. So definitely concurrent activity could cause this. If a key column is updated so that a row moves up in the index being seeked and is read twice, this can happen at read committed too.

Comment: **Please post the definition of `Price` including all constraints and indexes**

Comment: @MartinSmith Am I right in thinking that snapshot isolation level would prevent the possibility?

Comment: @MattGibson - Yes - and repeatable read would because the lock won't be released on the row as soon as it's read. Though repeatable read would block the presumably frequent data modification going on concurrently.

Comment: @Matt Gibson - I'm pretty sure the table is dropped. I've tried running the drop (F5), trying to select from it to make sure it's gone (F5), then creating the #p table (F5), and then running the insert, and the situation is the same. I've also disconnected and reconnected my session, and the table is definitely gone, and then I run the insert with same result. It seems snapshot isolation is not enabled on my server. I've updated the result with all definitions and constraints and the load and update frequency on the table.

Comment: Which of the two similar named indexes is the one actually being seeked in the plan?

Comment: The seek is on `IX_Price_idMarketplace_priceChangedDate_INC_idIsbn_lowestPrice`

Comment: Cool. So updates to `priceChangedDate` to make it a later date time than it was previously will move it to later in the index and if it had already been read it can then be read a second time per my answer.

Comment: You mention in your answer that you've duplicated this on `read committed`. Would you expect your same answer to hold true on `read uncommitted`?

Comment: @Trevor - yes, you would need at least repeatable read to avoid this with the  locking isolation levels, or RCSI. Though your work around with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` might be fine too dependant on the degree of consistency needed.

Comment: I'm flexible on consistency, but I've seen this problem way too many times, and I always just use ignore_dup_key, but I decided to really try to understand this today, and you've come to the rescue. This is really great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You hadn't supplied your table structure.

This is a repro with some assumed details that causes the problem at read committed (NB: now you have supplied the definition I can see in your case updates to the `priceChangedDate` column will move rows around in the `IX_Price_idMarketplace_priceChangedDate_INC_idIsbn_lowestPrice` index if that's the one being seeked)

### Connection 1 (Set up tables)

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE Price
  (
     SomeKey          INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     idIsbn           INT IDENTITY UNIQUE,
     idMarketplace    INT DEFAULT 3100,
     lowestPrice      SMALLMONEY DEFAULT $1.23,
     priceChangedDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
  );

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix
  ON Price(idMarketplace)
  INCLUDE (idIsbn, lowestPrice, priceChangedDate);

INSERT INTO Price
            (SomeKey)
SELECT number
FROM   master..spt_values
WHERE  number BETWEEN 1 AND 2000
       AND type = 'P';
```

### Connection 2

#### Concurrent DataModifications that move a row from the beginning of the seeked range `(3100,1)` to the end `(3100,2001)` and back again repeatedly.

```
USE tempdb;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
UPDATE Price SET SomeKey = 2001 WHERE SomeKey = 1
UPDATE Price SET SomeKey = 1 WHERE SomeKey = 2001
END
```

### Connection 3 (Do the insert into a temp table with a unique constraint)

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE #P
  (
     idIsbn           INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     price            SMALLMONEY,
     priceChangedDate DATETIME
  );

WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
      TRUNCATE TABLE #P

      INSERT INTO #P
                  (idIsbn,
                   price,
                   priceChangedDate)
      SELECT idIsbn,
             MIN(lowestPrice),
             MIN(priceChangedDate)
      FROM   Price p
      WHERE  p.idMarketplace = 3100
      GROUP  BY p.idIsbn
  END
```

[image]

The plan has no aggregate as there is a unique constraint on idIsbn (a unique constraint on idIsbn,idMarketplace would also work) therefore the group by can be optimised out as there are no duplicate values.

But at read committed isolation level shared row locks are released as soon as the row is read. So it is possible for a row to move places and be read a second time by the same seek or scan.

The index `ix` doesn't explicitly include `SomeKey` as a secondary key column but as it is not declared unique SQL Server silently includes the clustering key behind the scenes, hence updating that column value can move rows around in it.

Comment: Great answer, and it's really helped me understand this potential problem. (I do a lot of querying like this, but almost always from separate reporting databases/warehouses where the data is basically read-only, so I've never bumped into it in real life.)